# Is the inside of a sphere a hyperbolical surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature, noneuclidean-geometry

So since an elliptic surface with constant curvature would be a sphere, would a an hyperbolical surface with a constant curvature be the inside of a sphere if we were to go out from inside the sphere?  Many thanks.

Comment: If you take a triangle on the sphere, it is the same from outside and from inside with the sum of all angles to be $>\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, from the point of view of a surface, there is no distinction between "the surface from the inside" and "the surface from the outside.

The model surface with constant negative curvature (and hence the hyperbolic analogue of the $2$-sphere) is the [hyperbolic plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_space). A theorem of Hilbert states that, unlike the $2$-sphere, the hyperbolic plane cannot be embedded isometrically into $\Bbb R^3$. One *can* still find a surface in $\Bbb R^3$ that has negative constant curvature (i.e., embed the hyperbolic plane locally), e.g., half of a [tracticoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudosphere). Unlike the hyperbolic plane, any such space is incomplete.